# jquery create your own function?

Tags: jquery, function

I have a block of code that I would like to execute every 10 seconds or so and also on a buttons click event.  Should I create a function to save on coding repetation ?  I will have alot of buttons on the page that will fire this block of code, but realise I can use a class selector to trigger the code.  I need the timer interval as 3rd parties will be able to change the values that the code is checking, I am not to concerned about the timer been super accurate.

How would I change the code into a function?  I have seen a few examples for creating functions but I haven't seen anything that fits my requirements.

```
//This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code
$('img.checkStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
    $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
    var data="url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?      t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d="  +       $x10Device ;

    $.ajax({                  
        url:"urlencode.php",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) { 
            myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
            var Nmyd = myd.charAt(3);
            if (Nmyd == '2'){
                $('img').attr('src','lightbulbon.png')
            }
            else{
                $('img').attr('src','lightbulboff.png')};    
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {   
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for any thoughts and help

Comment: _"Should I create a function to save on coding repetation?"_ - Yes.

Comment: You define a function using `function funName(argList,...) { code here }` and anything that is supposed to be variable in your function should be passed as argument to it. Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: Are you sure the code shown works? I notice inside the Ajax success handler you are using `$('img').attr('src','lightbulbon.png')` which will set the src of every img element on the page to the same thing.

Comment: This code is very close to the working model, the sctructure is all correct.  But you are right NNNNNNN I replaced the $('img') with a variable to handle that issue, just not on my development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a block of code needs to be called from multiple places it is definitely a good idea to encapsulate it in a function and then call the function as needed. So:

```
function someFuncName() {
    // your block of code here
}
```

Give the function a meaningful name according to what it does, in your case perhaps `checkStatus` would be appropriate.

> *"I would like to execute every 10 seconds or so"*

OK, you can use the [`setInterval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) for that:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(someFuncName, 10000); // specify delay in milliseconds
// and later, if you need to cancel the interval:
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Notice that when you pass `someFuncName` to `setInterval()` you do *not* include parentheses after its name - that's because you are not calling the function, you are passing a reference to it to `setInterval()` and then JS calls the function for you at the specified interval.

> *"I will have alot of buttons on the page that will fire this block of code, but realise I can use a class selector to trigger the code"*

OK, so bind your function as a click handler for all elements of a specified class:

```
$(".classOfButtonsHere").on("click", someFuncName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can try something like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
   var timer  = setInterval("timerAjaxFunction()" , 10000) 
   function timerAjaxFunction ()
   {
      // your ajax code for 10 seconds comes here...     
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".selctorClassofbutton").on("click",function(){ //button to call function
        clearInterval(timer);
        timerAjaxFunction ();
        timer  = setInterval("timerAjaxFunction()" , 10000);
      })
   });       
  </script>
```